# Error launching my Flutter app on IOS device getting this message from xCode "Unable to launch "app " because it has an invalid code signature"

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter, xcode, apple-developer

Hi guys I hope you are fine and in good health.

Did anyone face this issue when trying to launch Flutter app on iPhone physical device I got an error about trusting the Apple developer team and I should go to
General -> VPN & Device Management
And then trust the team profile there, but when I went there I didn't find any teams or accounts even after I plugged in the iPhone to the Mac and XCode detect it and trust the iPhone and added it to developer team devices but still can't find the device management page and the app won't run.
PS: I tried every Stackoverflow solution from cleaning the profiles folder to unselecting the auto sign-in in XCode but nothing worked.

[image]

This is the screenshot in Xcode when I choose personal Team I get an error but when I choose Apps Team it accept (still not running in both cases)

[image: screen shot of Xcode]

[image]

Comment: The message i got from xCode : 

The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to launch com.bash.gate because it has an invalid code signature, inadequate entitlements or its profile has not been explicitly trusted by the user.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same issue, open the ios folder in xcode, Then open the Signing & Capabilities, after that you have to check that the Team is valid this is an example of an incorrect way an how it appears, the solution is changing the Bundle identifier name and if the Team name is invalid change it to Personal Team, then you can debug the App. Meaby this will help you.

[image]

Comment: when I choose personal team I get an error from Xcode but when I choose apps it accept it but still not running (when I open the app in Xcode by default is Apps Team). 
I will attach image in a comment bellow.